# Regex to return start time (#t=) from YouTube URL

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm looking for a way that I can get a URL like any of these:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nlwa0ZWrO8g#t=1m30s?someweirdthing
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nlwa0ZWrO8g#t=90s&anotherweirdthing
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nlwa0ZWrO8g#t=90
```

to return values like these:

```
1m30s
90s
90
```

Is this possible with a single regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
youtube.com\S+#t=((\d+m)?(\d+[s]?)?)
```

locate the value of capture group 1 and it will return

```
1m30s
90s
90
```

That being said, it is likely better to use Split() as suggested by Blender.

In javascript group matching is as simple as

```
var youtubeString = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nlwa0ZWrO8g#t=1m30s?someweirdthing";
var myRegexp      = /youtube.com\S+#t=((\d+m)?(\d+[s]?)?)/g;
var match         = myRegexp.exec(youtubeString);
alert(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `.split()`:

```
> 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nlwa0ZWrO8g#t=1m30s'.split('#t=')[1]
"1m30s"
```

As for a regex, you could use:

```
/#t=([^&$?]+)/
```

Comment: See my edits to the URLs, which wouldn't work with your solution.